# Make sure I'm selecting and running through all elements for an "each" statment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a script that keeps our main button disabled until specific field requriments are met.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {//check if all are filled else disable submit
    var inputFields = jQuery('#list-item-cc input, #field_28_50 input,#field_28_18 input');                             
    inputFields.keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        inputFields.each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).val().length == 0) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            jQuery('#gform_submit_button_28').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            jQuery('#gform_submit_button_28').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
```

I'm having trouble thinking of a way to ensure my **inputFields** variable can be passed to my `inputFields.each(function()` in a way that would allow the loop.

We're not worried about all input fields. Just the specific inputs in our `inputFields` variable.

Is this an effective way to ensure a button is disabled if certain fields are not filled out and can I create the selector in the way that i did and use that in an `each` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using gravity forms? In that case I would add a css class to each field that you want to validate. That way you don't have to go searching for ID's and change the code for multiple forms.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/css-ready-classes/

Here is a fiddle in which I pretend that I added "ensure-filled" to each item in the gravity forms builder

https://jsfiddle.net/dokLz4hm/3/

Also note that I added a .trim() to the value so that blank spaces aren't counted as input and made the submit button generic so it would work with any field in a form that contains the `ensure-filled` class

Html

```
<div>
  <div id="arbitraty_id_1">
    <input type="text" class="ensure-filled" />
  </div>
  <div id="arbitraty_id_2">
    <input type="text" class="ensure-filled" />
  </div>
  <div id="arbitraty_id_3">
    <input type="text" class="ensure-filled" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var inputFields = $('.ensure-filled');                             
   inputFields.keyup(function() {
       var empty = false;
       inputFields.each(function() {
           if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
               empty = true;
           }
       });
       $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', empty);
   })
})
```